# Is there a way to have a placeholder on a combobox?

Tags: qt, qml

I want to build a `ComboBox` component that the first time we get to it, it has a text has a placeholder.

For example:

|   panel language  |

and when i click it i see the options:

| --  English  -- |

| Portuguese |

|  -- French --  |

If i select one thats what will now appear visible on the combobox

Im using  `qt` 5.12 and still haven't find a way to do that.

With html it's easy to do what i want:

```
<style>
    select:invalid { color: gray; }
</style>
<form>
    <select required>
        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please Choose...</option>
        <option value="0">Open when powered (most valves do this)</option>
        <option value="1">Closed when powered, auto-opens when power is cut</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

How can a similar thing be done with `qml`?

Comment: I can only offer a partial answer since I'm not familar with QML. In C++, you can access the QLineEdit using the QComboBox::lineEdit() method. Once you have that, you have access to the QLineEdit's placeHolderText property. I hope someone can expand on this to give you an answer in QML.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be done using [`displayText`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-combobox.html#displayText-prop) and [`currentIndex`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-combobox.html#currentIndex-prop):

```
ComboBox {
    currentIndex: -1
    displayText: currentIndex === -1 ? "Please Choose..." : currentText
    model: [
        "Open when powered (most valves do this)",
        "Closed when powered, auto-opens when power is cut"
    ]
}
```